# Synchronisation application and data tracking by composite primary key

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I need to make application to mirroring all tables from MS SQL Server into anther DB server.

My app makes query to db in cycle to get rows by primary key column and I'am storing primary key column value as start point for select next row.

Traking changes in case primary key consist of only one field is simple, but for composite primary keys that consist of several fields it doesn't.

**Is there simple way to track changes by primary key that could be universal for any table that use composite primary key and it avoid dataloss?**

Comment: Can you provide an example, input or expected output?

Comment: If you want to mirror SQL Server to SQL Server I suggest you look into existing [built in technologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/types-of-replication?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: If you do need to use your own implementation I suggest you start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: To answer your question: I am not aware of any universal ways. PK is, more or less, just a unique constraint on a set of columns' values. You need to record last processed values for all PK columns or create another another single column to act as a PK. Have you also considered a scenario where a table might not have a PK?

Comment: @Alex Have you also considered a scenario where a table might not have a PK? - No

Comment: @Alex Could you suggest some framework or article or thomething how to  track data that has composit key ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not aware of any. Why are you trying to write your own tool, when "replication" already exists?

Comment: @Alex because it is not exactly replication. I need loading data to my server (not MS SQL) from MS Sql server. Thanks for reply!